# How To Use Fluent Syntax For Multiple Views

Tags: entity-framework

The following statement will return a "BestAddress" Entity from the `demov_sel_best_address` SQL Server view. It will also return the Person entity of the owner of the address. It works fine.

`_ctx.BestAddresses.FromSql($"select * from [demo].[demov_sel_best_address] addr where addr.PersonID = 1")
.Include(x => x.People).FirstOrDefault();`

How can the statement be re-written to:

a.  Get the Person first.  Something like:

`_ctx.People
.Include(x => x.BestAddress.FromSql($"select * from [demo].[demov_sel_best_address]")
.where(x => x.PersonID == 1)`

b.  Join 2 views.  Something like:

`_ctx.People.FromSql($"select * from [demo].[demov_sel_people] p")
.Include(x => x.BestAddress.FromSql($"select * from [demo].[demov_sel_best_address]")
.where(x => x.PersonID == 1)`

I'm using the following:

EF Core 2.0.0
VS 2017
SQL Server 2016

Comment: Why don't you use LINQ statements?

Comment: It is a LINQ statement.

Comment: OK, why not LINQ *only* statements?

Comment: There are cases when the LINQ becomes to complicated and a View/Stored Procedure/Indexed View, etc... makes more sense.  There are also cases when you need total control of the SQL for performance reasons.  I'm not really interested in debating if this is the best approach.  I am interested in mastering LINQ/EF.  Does LINQ/EF support the use of multiple views in a single query and - if so - what is the syntax?

Comment: Yeah, but that's basically a SQL question, not LINQ, not EF. EF supports *anything* that produces at least all columns required to build `Person` entities. EF isn't interested in whatever you put in the raw SQL string. Which also means: when using `FromSql` it's in your own hands, EF can no longer guarantee that it actually makes sense what you put in there.

Comment: Thanks Gert.  

Can someone else please weigh-in?  Isn't the EF team supposed to be monitoring the submissions with the the entity-framework tag?

Comment: Also, `Include` will never work like this. It only accepts a property-access expression as parameter, *nothing else*. An EF team member will tell you exactly the same things.

Answer (score 0):

EF Core can treat Views EXACTLY the same as a table as long as they are configured that way.  To setup the view as a table:

1. Define a Data Model that matches the columns returned from the view.

   public class BestAddress
   {
       [Key]
       public int ID { get; set; }

   ```
   public string Addr1 { get; set; }

   public string Addr2 { get; set; }

   etc...

   //Add navigation to join to other Entities.
   public int PersonID { get; set; }
   public Person Person { get; set; }

   etc...
   ```
2. Map the Entity to your view using something like:

   **[Table("demov_sel_best_address", Schema = "demo")]**

   public class BestAddress

   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set; }

   etc...
3. Add the Entity to the context.

   **public DbSet < BestAddress > BestAddresses { get; set; }**
4. Now, you can write Linq against the object:

   ```
       var query = _ctx
           .BestAddresses
           .AsNoTracking()
           .Where(x => x.ID == id)
       etc...
   ```
5. The Entity can be incorporated into other entities:

   [Table("People", Schema = "demo")]

   public class Person 
   {
       [Key]
       public int ID { get; set; }

   ```
   public int BestAddressID{ get; set; }
   public BestAddress BestAddress{ get; set; }
   ```

Now, the view can be included in the normal Linq syntax:

```
_ctx.People
.Include(x => x.BestAddress)
.where(x => x.ID == 1)
```

Other views can be added using the same technique.  Then, they can be joined using the same technique.